# changing the content of a nav/div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav like this:

```
<nav class="subnav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="a.html">This goes to content A.</a></li>
  <li><a href="a.html">This goes to content B.</a></li>
  <li><a href="a.html">This goes to content C.</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

and another one like this:

```
<nav class="subnav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="1.html">This goes to content 1.</a></li>
  <li><a href="1.html">This goes to content 2.</a></li>
  <li><a href="3.html">This goes to content 3.</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

I want an  element that will swap my subnav into another using onclick event. If the user clicks Alphabetical Group, it should remove the second one and use the first. If the user clicks on Numerical Group, it should remove the first one and show the second.

There should be a default state too.

How can i do this ?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: yes really hard please be little more specicific

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML

```
<nav class="subnav" id="alphabetical">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="a.html">This goes to content A.</a></li>
  <li><a href="a.html">This goes to content B.</a></li>
  <li><a href="a.html">This goes to content C.</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="subnav" id="numeric" style="display:none;">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="1.html">This goes to content 1.</a></li>
  <li><a href="1.html">This goes to content 2.</a></li>
  <li><a href="3.html">This goes to content 3.</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<input type="button" id="one" value="Show Alphabetical" />
<input type="button" id="two" value="Show Numeric" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#one").click(function(){
        $("#numeric").hide();
        $("#alphabetical").show();           
    });

    $("#two").click(function(){
        $("#alphabetical").hide();
        $("#numeric").show();           
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L67b6/1/)

Comment: @Aniruddha It is better if you use the same button to switch mode.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to attach a unique class to both uls:

```
<nav class="subnav alphabetical">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="a.html">This goes to content A.</a></li>
  <li><a href="a.html">This goes to content B.</a></li>
  <li><a href="a.html">This goes to content C.</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="subnav numerical">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="1.html">This goes to content 1.</a></li>
  <li><a href="1.html">This goes to content 2.</a></li>
  <li><a href="3.html">This goes to content 3.</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Then in JS/jQuery:

```
$('.subnav').on('click', function(e){
  var $target = $(e.target);
  $target.hide();
  if($target.hasClass('numerical')) {
    $('.alphabetical').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.numerical').show();
  }
});
```